# C++17: What does "operator with precedence below cast" mean in "fold" concept?

Tags: casting, operator-keyword, fold, c++17, operator-precedence

The website of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold gives an example of how to use fold concept, and it says:

```
Note
If the expression used as init or as pack has an operator with precedence    
below cast at the top level, it can be parenthesed:

template<typename ...Args>
int sum(Args&&... args) {
//    return (args + ... + 1 * 2); // Error: operator with precedence below cast
    return (args + ... + (1 * 2)); // OK
}
```

As a non-native English speaker, I don't quit get the sentence:

```
has an operator with precedence below cast at the top level
```

What does it actually mean, and it the example, what does it indicate?
Could you help to explain this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It means anything below line 3 in the [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The casting operator (`(Typename)expr`) has a very high precedence in [C++'s operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Very few operators have higher precedence than that. Operators of cast level or greater precedence are very special operations, usually applying to a single expression.

In the expression `args + ... + 1 * 2`, the `...` applies to everything both on the left and the right. But what does "on the right" really mean? Does it mean just the `+ 1` part, or does it mean `+ 1 * 2`?

In the case of operators with high precedence, it's clear what the intent is. For example, `args + ... + func()`, it's clear that the `()` function call operator applies to `func` and not to `args + ... + func`. It's so unlikely that you would want the latter that you are forced to use parenthesis explicitly if you did (`(args + ... + func)()`).

However for precedence levels below 3 in the chart, things become much more cloudy for people to understand. So instead of using the normal precedence rules, C++ forces the user to be explicit about it. You can have `args + ... + (1 * 2)` or `(args + ... + 1) * 2`. But you have to be clear which one you want.

Comment: Since fold expressions are `( exp1 op ... op exp2 )` with the parens, I doubt that there's an actual parsing ambiguity. It's probably there so that it's clear to humans, not just compilers.

Answer (score 2):

It means that if an expression with several operators is ambiguous, operators that are "above cast" will be called before the cast operator, and operators that are "below cast" will be called after the cast operator. As in `2 + 2 * 2` multiplication should be executed before addition, resulting 6, but not 8.

Let's consider the following two classes which are castable to each other:

```cpp
class E2;

class E1 {
public:

  operator E2();

  E1 operator++(int) {
    std::cout << "E1 Post-inc\n";
    return *this;
  }

  E1 operator*(const E1&) {
    std::cout << "E1 * E1\n";
    return *this;
  }
};

class E2 {
public:

  operator E1() {
    std::cout << "Cast E1 -> E2\n";
    return E1();
  }

  E2 operator++(int) {
    std::cout << "E2 Post-inc\n";
    return *this;
  }

  E2 operator*(const E2&) {
    std::cout << "E2 * E2\n";
    return *this;
  }
};

E1::operator E2() {
  std::cout << "Cast E2 -> E1\n";
  return E2();
}
```

Then let's declare

```
E1 e1;
E2 e2;
```

and do

```
(E1)e2++;
```

Both E1 and E2 have operator `++`, so what should be done first in this expression: cast or increment? [Precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) answers that increment should be done first, so the program prints

```
E2 Post-inc
Cast E1 -> E2
```

Then, let's try a more complicated example:

```
e1 * (E1)e2++;
```

Here we have 3 actions (in order of their appearance in code): multiplication, cast and increment. What thw order if execution will be? Precedence table says that increment is the first, cast is the second (it's below the increment) and multiplication is the last, as it's below both of them. So the output will be:

```
E2 Post-inc
Cast E1 -> E2
E1 * E1
```

Note that you can easily reorder the operations using parentheses. For example, if we replace `e1 * (E1)e2++;` with `(e1 * (E1)e2)++;`, we'll get

```
Cast E1 -> E2
E1 * E1
E1 Post-inc
```